# Using Solve_ivp for PDE

Tags: pde

I am trying to build a python code that solves a set of coupled differential equations which will be spatially discretized by method of lines advancing in time. I am planning to use solve_ivp. In my problem, the conservation of species include product of gas density and mass fraction of species in the time derivative. My question is how do i handle multiple time dependant variables in single equation in solve_ivp?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1S5e.png)

I used solve_ivp previously for coupled equations but had one variable integrated over time in that case.